# Create unique-member collections in Swift

Tags: cocoa, swift, nsset

I don't see any way of guaranteeing uniqueness of the members of a Swift array/collection like Cocoa `NSSet`s.  If this is true, then I wonder what else is missing from Swift, vs Cocoa?

What am I missing, if anything?

Comment: A `Dictionary<MyType,()>` acts basically as a set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're missing is that NSSet and the rest of Foundation, Cocoa, etc. is still there and always will be.

**EDIT:** In Swift 1.2, Set is a native Swift type and you'll use that instead.

There's absolutely nothing wrong with using NSSet when you need to. Here's an example from my own code:

```
class TracksViewController : UITableViewController {
    // ...
    var observers = NSMutableSet()
    // ...
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        func noteNowPlayingItem (note:NSNotification?) {
            // ...
        }
        // do it now!
        noteNowPlayingItem(nil)
        // and do it later, when now playing item notification arrives
        let ob = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChangeNotification, 
            object: nil, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), 
            usingBlock: noteNowPlayingItem)
        self.observers.addObject(ob)
    }
    // ...
}
```

So there I am using an NSMutableSet as a way of storing notification observers so I can do memory management later. No problem.

Notice, however, that just in that little snippet of code I am taking advantage of Swift features that put it head and shoulders above Objective-C in my opinion:

- The NSMutableSet property does not have to be initialized in code (e.g. in an initializer, or in `viewDidLoad`); I do it right when I declare it. You can't do that in Objective-C. So this is safe; this property will never accidentally be nil (has that ever happened to you??).
- I use function-in-function, so that I can both call a closure and pass it. Yes, you can do the same thing in Objective-C (give a block a name), but is this syntax easier or what? I had to look up the "named closure" syntax every time I used it; now I spend my time writing code, not looking up obscure syntax that I can't write or read.

Indeed, just sticking with arrays for a moment, there are lots of times when you have a Swift Array but you need to cast it to an NSArray, or pass an Array into a Cocoa method that takes an NSArray, so as to call some Foundation method that has no Swift equivalent. It's not a problem.

Comment: I should also mention that the "bridge" between Swift Array and Foundation NSArray is extremely lightweight.

Comment: OK... so I guess I'm missing the point of learning Swift if I can do everything with Obj-C which I feell comfortable with now.

Comment: @spokane-dude That is a very reasonable question, and you could certainly pose it separately, though I don't think it would prove suitable for Stack Overflow as it would probably be closed as "opinion only".

Comment: However, I have opinions on the matter, having now translated several apps into Swift, and I strongly recommend learning and using Swift. My code is much cleaner and safer, easier to read and maintain, and lots of other yummy goodness.

Comment: Plus there is absolutely nothing wrong with mix-and-match; you can leave some of your code as Objective-C (and to do some things, you must; for example, Swift cannot pass a pointer-to-C-function, which some APIs need).

Comment: Thanks Matt... that helps... I'll continue with learning Swift...  btw, I remember you now... I bought your book... looking forward to iOS 8 if you're going to do it... :D

Comment: @spokane-dude And I added some further example / discussion to my answer. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

What @matt says is true, there is nothing wrong with using NSSet from Objective-C, as Apple has made it pretty nice to be able to integrate Swift and Objective-C in the same app. Regarding your reply, remember Swift isn't fully baked yet, and there may be many more APIs available to us in future releases, such as a unique set API, reflection, etc.  This should not deter you from learning Swift, as well as Objective-C, so don't give up! :-) This may be a good thing for you to file a radar with Apple on; as I can see a definite need for an NSSet-like architecture in Swift, and if, some day, Objective-C goes by the wayside, Swift would need a standalone API for it, rather than relying on Objective-C's NSSet.

Comment: Well you are right that you can still use NSSet but then you lose all the goodies you get from Swift. You can't use enums or structs in NSSet. It's much better to roll out your own Swift set implementation